# I sent $50 worth of bitcoins from coinbase wallet to bittrex wallet but received only a third of it in the bittrex

Tags: transactions

I sent $50 worth of bitcoins from coinbase wallet to bittrex wallet but received only a third of it in the bittrex. Could someone please explain if the i will get more bitcoins later or did i just lose it?
This has never happened before as i have done this transfer previously as well.
It shows confirmed on coinbase but it still doesn't show all my bitcoins on bittrex wallet.

EDIT - i just found out that 66% was the fee they charged me. Why is that? They generally charge 0.25% but this is ridiculously high.

Comment: The transaction fee is a fixed amount, not a percentage

Comment: don't confuse: 0,25% are the fees of the exchange-website for trades, withdrawals, etc.. the exchange-website gets this 0,25%. the 66% of your 50$ are network-fees. when coinbase executes your withdrawal-transaction, they are sending a transaction to the bitcoin-network and set a fee (for example 0.0025btc (~35usd)). the miner which creates a new block in the blockchain where this transaction is included got the network-transaction-fee. i think it is very sad when exchanges don't allow their users to set the network-fee for their transactions. but this is unfortunately normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, Bitcoin's transaction fees are getting excessively expensive. That could be why altcoins like BCH are gaining popularity

Comment: Please keep politics out of answers here as much as possible :)

Comment: But 66%? I never knew that it would be this high.

Comment: you must usually pay or every transaction. the bitcoin-network-fee does not depend on the amount of btc you are tranfering. if you are transfering small funds it is unfortunately virtually normal that the percentage of fees is higher. the fee is not higher if you transfering very high amounts of btc